# Searching local library in Kodi never finds anything

Tags: kodi

I have Kodi 18.6 running on Linux Mint 20.3. When I click the big search button and try to search anything in the local DB, nothing is ever found:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have lot of media in the library, both movies and TV Series. Not finding a single item whatever I type is really weird. I also have Kore app for Kodi on my phone, and it has no trouble finding any media.

What should I change in the settings for the local media to be found using search?

Comment: @jsotola I edited the post... but it seemed kinda implied that I am asking what to do so this problem is no longer a problem.